# Problema com criação de lista

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou tentando criar uma função que tem como entrada uma lista. A função calcula o numero de caracteres de cada componente da lista e devolve uma outra lista com os números. Após isso teria que colocar em ordem crescente a primeira lista.

```
textos = ["casa", "mamamia", "jejum", "girimum"]
def calcula_assinatura(palavra):
    x = len(palavra)
    return x

 def verifica_assinatura(textos):
     assinatura = []
     for i in range (0,len(textos)):
       calcula_assinatura(i)
       assinatura = assinaura.append[i]
     x = assinatura.sort()
     return x
```

Comment: Veja a duplicata que foi sugerida acima, pelo que entendi é isso que vc quer. Se não é isso que precisa, vc pode [edit] a pergunta explicando qual o resultado que deseja

Comment: realmente era isso mesmo, do modo que eu estava fazendo, estava escrevendo muito codigo. muito obrigado pela ajuda mesmo.

Comment: Olá Brunno, se você conseguiu resolver seu problema, peço que marque a pergunta como resolvido, no símbolo 'v' na resposta que te atendeu, para que fique registrado que está pergunta já foi resolvida. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Ola, eu penso isto o que voce esta olhando por. desculpe para meu Portuguese, sou americano e aprendendo.

```
textos = ["casa", "mamamia", "jejum", "girimum"]


def calcula_assinatura(palavras):
    caracteres = []
    for palavra in palavras:
        caracteres.append(len(palavra))
    return caracteres


caracteres = calcula_assinatura(textos)
caracteres.sort()
print(caracteres)
```

Comment: obrigado pela atenção e pelo código, de inicial seria parecido com esse código, mas a primeira resposta sanou minhas duvidas.De inicio eu estava planejando fazer ele assim, ajudou muito.

Answer (score 1):

Saudações Bruno Boff,

Na primeira função você estava calculando a quantidade de elementos da lista e não a quantidade de caracteres que tinha em cada elemento.

Não entendi a segunda função, mas se a intenção era retornar a primeira lista ordenada, então para simplificar coloquei como o segundo valor retornado na mesma função.

```
palavras = ["casa", "mamamia", "jejum", "girimum"]

def calcula_assinatura(lista):
    total = []
    for i in lista:
        total.append(len(i))
    return total, sorted(lista)

total, palavras = calcula_assinatura(palavras)

print(total)
print(palavras)
```

Comment: A primeira resposta caiu como uma luva, mas obrigado pela atenção e pelo código ajudou no meu desenvolvimento, a entender um pouco mais da estrutura.